# Code editor commenting styles

Tags: javascript, php, sublimetext2, coda

Which code editor use the commenting style below as default for PHP, CSS, and JS?

```
/*
 * this is a multi-line comment, which needs to be used
 * for explanations, and preferably be OUTSIDE the a
 * function's or class' and provide information to developers
 * that would not belong to a generated API documentation.
 */
```

Is it possible to use that on Sublime Text and Coda as default? rather than typing in manually.

Comment: For Sublime, sure of course. It's just a matter of [getting the right plugin for it](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Comment-Snippets)

Comment: Many could. PHPStorm does this: `Ctrl+Slash` Comment or uncomment a line; `Ctrl+Shift+Slash` block comment.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the plugin [DocBlockr](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/DocBlockr) for Sublime Text (I don't use Coda).

To install it, just install [the Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation), open the command palette (Ctrl + Shift + P), type `package control install package` (I personally do `pci`), then search for `DocBlockr`.

It will not change your normal comments, but it will do this :

```
/**
```

press tab or enter

```
/**
 * 
 */
```

It will also add lines accordingly, e.g:

```
/**
 * cursor on this line
 */
```

press enter

```
/**
 * cursor on this line
 * 
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

In coda you can block comment by Selecting your text you want to comment out and press `CMD + /`

It doesn't add `*` to every line however, if that's what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: It also comments the code according to the syntax mode currently selected.